# What is the difference in displaying xml data using html browsers?

Tags: xml-rpc

What is the difference in displaying xml data using html browser such as firefox,internet exporer,netscape navigator etc. in terms of how text, images etc are display on a computer screen?

Comment: can you specify more on what differences you are looking for.  Also are you displaying to a human user or trying to process the xml in some way?

Comment: this is a non-question, please explain more

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little bit confusing, since XML is a base technology, it does not define how to represent anything so the question itself hasn't a lot of sense.

A plain xml file will be displayed as a collapsable tree of text data since any xml file is just a structured text file that follows some basic and simple rules (such as tag syntax, special chars, etc.).

As divo said if you define a stylesheet inside xml what IExplorer will render will be the result of applying that stylesheet. That applies to both CSS stylesheets and XSLT transformation stylesheets.

Moreover if your xml is actually xhtml it will be rendered as a normal HTML page. That is because IExplorer supports XHTML specification which is a standard defined by means of XML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

some specialties of Internet Explorer (in contrast to simple text editors) is that you should be aware of are e.g. that white space is removed and empty tags are replaced by single elements (  becomes ).

IE also will execute any XSL stylesheet included in your XML.